# i want to Get Single Value From SQLite Database [C#]

Tags: c#, sqlite

i am trying to get single value from sqlite database but i am facing error

so i can do some action to this value or check it

[image: a busy cat]

```
dbConnection StartConn = new dbConnection();
            SQLiteConnection MyConnetion = StartConn.GetConnection();

            SQLiteCommand Cm = new SQLiteCommand(" select * from Users where user_username = '" + txtBxUserName.Text + "' and user_password = '" + txtBxPassword.Text + "'", MyConnetion);

            MyConnetion.Open();
            SQLiteDataReader dr = Cm.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();

            int count = Convert.ToInt32(Cm.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count != 0)
            {
                globalVariables.userFullName = dr["user_name"].ToString();
                globalVariables.appLoginUser = dr["user_username"].ToString();
                globalVariables.appPasswordUser = dr["user_password"].ToString();
                globalVariables.userPermissions = dr["user_permissions"].ToString();

                mainForm newMainForm = new mainForm();
                newMainForm.Show();
                this.Hide();

                MyConnetion.Close();
```

Comment: `globalVariables` appears to be null.

Comment: Does `globalVariables` exist in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Your dtareader has no rows, and thats causes the error. try it like this:

```
if(dr.Read())
{
    // rest of your code
}
```